# Lightbox iFrame problem

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, lightbox

I have an iFrame that is loaded with a lightbox. The problem I am having is this. I want the parent page to redirect to a different page after a link in the lightbox pop up is clicked. Does this make sense? Please help. Thank you in advance.

I received this answer yesterday from yokoloko (thank you very much) But I am not sure which parts of the code I have to fill in with my information.  Can somebody please help? Thanks.

From Yokoloko:

The only way is to define a javascript function in your parent frame to be called in your child frame.

eg in your parent frame if your using jQuery :

```
function redirectFromFrame(link){
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

and in your lighbox frame you should have something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(parent.redirectFromFrame($(this).attr('href')));
});
```

Comment: this first goes in the main page, the second goes on in the iframe page.assuming you are loading a page you have access to its code in the iframe.

Comment: For the code that I put on the main page, where it says link do I put my link in both spots or do I leave it saying link.  and for the code on the iframe page, what do i put for 'a' and 'href'

Answer (score 1):

I would just use something like this (and this code goes within your iframe)

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        window.parent.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

the `$('a')` refers to the a tag within your iframe that you want the redirection to take place on

Comment: What if it is not being called from an 'a' tag rather an input button.  and what if there are more than one 'a' tag on the page? do I give the 'a' tag a class name?

Comment: You can give the element an ID and then use the following `$('#ID_HERE')` Or if you want to use a class `$('.CLASSNAME')` or if you want to use both `$('#ID_HERE, .CLASSNAME')`

Comment: None of the solutions are working.  I need to have a link within the iFrame redirect the parent page.  It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: try $(document).ready(function(){  $('a').click(function() {
        window.parent.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    });
 }}  in the iframe page.